# Getting realtime notification whenever a new friend request is received MERN Stack using Socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, socket.io

I am trying to add a functionality in my web app where whenever a new friend request is received in the database (mongodb) then i get a notification through from backend (Node.js) to my frontend (React.js)

Now i researched about this functionality and get to know about **socket.io** but the problem is the solutions i found which were using socket.io were kind of a brute force according to me ,

In those solutions they were querying the database inside the socket.emit(),

Now according to me if I keep querying the database every 4-5 seconds is it a good approach to do that doesn't it put load on database?

What is the right way to do this?

What i have tried so far is finding a better solution than querying the database again and again till i get an update. But i had no luck ..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to connect frontend with backend using websocket/socket.io and as soon as you add a new object the server should push the data to frontend. You don't have to run a database query every 4-5 second. Write a server push event in your data.save() function. So as soon as you create a new object, the backend sends data to frontend.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I didn't really get what you are saying , what I want to do is when I click on send friend request on front end then the end user(the one to whom I sent the request) should get the notification , now according to your approach the server knows that something is pushed to the database , but how does it work when a user does not even know that a new request have been popped up in his/her database? how the server will get to know that?